# docker-compose up can't find module, but running from bash works

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I've been building a Node.js app on Docker, and following the advice in John Lees-Miller's excellent [Lessons from Building a Node App in Docker](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html) for setting up my environment.  Everything has been working fine for a week or two, but today I started running into an issue that I cannot figure out.

In a nutshell, I can no longer run the app via `docker-compose up`; I'm getting a node error for newly added module depedencies:

```
sfsftp_1  | module.js:327
sfsftp_1  |     throw err;
sfsftp_1  |     ^
sfsftp_1  | 
sfsftp_1  | Error: Cannot find module 'eval'
sfsftp_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
sfsftp_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
sfsftp_1  |     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
sfsftp_1  |     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
sfsftp_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/sfsftp/lib/reformatter.js:4:13)
sfsftp_1  |     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
sfsftp_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
sfsftp_1  |     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
sfsftp_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
sfsftp_1  |     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

However, if I run a bash shell:

```
docker-compose run --rm sfsftp /bin/bash
```

and start the node app from inside the container with `node sftp.js`, the app starts up fine!

I initially had this issue earlier today with the module `jsonminify`, which I had recently added to the project; I believe I had run the app both ways (`docker-compose up` and `docker-compose run` via bash) since making that change, but perhaps not?  In the interest of expediency, I decided to punt on the issue, and removed my use on `jsonminify`.  Later, I needed to add the `eval` module to my project, and now I'm getting the same error for that module.  I feel like the `docker-compose up` command is using an older copy of the image than the `docker-compose run` command, one without my recent changes.

When I've added the modules, I've followed the process in the article - use `docker-compose run` to get a bash shell and running `npm install --save module` inside the running instance.  My `package.json` and `npm-shrinkwrap.json` files are being updated, and I see the `eval` module in both.

I'm still fairly new to developing in Docker containers, so I've reached the point of "let's try this"; so far I've tried:

- `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up`
- `docker-compose up --build`
- `docker-compose build --no-cache` followed by `docker-compose up`
- `docker run -p 22:9001 sftpdocker_sfsftp`

The last one worked - running docker directly, instead of via docker-compose.  But this loses some of the benefits of the setup.  How do I make docker-compose work?

For reference, here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# prepared with reference to http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html
# Current LTS Node version
FROM node:4.6.0

# Let's not run as Root.  And, update to recent NPM
RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app &&\
  npm install --global npm@3.7.5

ENV HOME=/home/app

# Get what we need for npm install
COPY package.json npm-shrinkwrap.json $HOME/sfsftp/
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*

# and install dependencies
USER app
WORKDIR $HOME/sfsftp
RUN npm install && npm cache clean

# do this after dependencies, so that if only the app changes, npm install won't be rerun
USER root
COPY . $HOME/sfsftp
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*
USER app

# Start it up!
CMD ["node", "sftp.js"]
```

and `docker-compose.yml`:

```
sfsftp:
  build: .
  ports:
    - '22:9001'
  volumes:
    - .:/home/app/sfsftp
    - /home/app/sfsftp/node_modules
```

and finally, `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sftp2sf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "sftp.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node sftp.js",
    "test": "mocha",
    "coverage": "istanbul cover _mocha -- -R spec && open coverage/lcov-report/index.html"
  },
  "author": "Jason Clark <jason.clark@example.com>",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "buffer-equal-constant-time": "^1.0.1",
    "byline": "^5.0.0",
    "eval": "^0.1.1",
    "fast-csv": "^2.3.0",
    "jsforce": "^1.7.0",
    "jsonminify": "^0.4.1",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.3",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    "ssh2": "^0.5.2",
    "through": "^2.3.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "mocha": "^3.1.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.6",
    "stream-to-array": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

**Update:** To address a proposed solution, of removing the volumes section of the docker-compose.yml:  The volumes section is an important part of this setup, and allows my local host to share files with the running docker image during development, except the node_modules which only live in the image; see the linked article for full explanation.  It is worth nothing that I've used this setup with those volume statements since starting on this project, and there are at least a dozen other Node modules that were installed the same way, and they are not causing the exception - if I remove `eval`, the code works.

**Update 17 Nov 2016:** This just seemed to fix itself; after switching gears to a higher-priority project for several days, I no longer had the problem.  I don't believe in bugs fixing themselves, but I cannot figure out what I may have done to resolve the issue.  Today, I had to add a new node module to the project (`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm sfsftp /bin/bash`, `npm install --save module` from inside the running shell, `docker-compose build`) and now the problem is back, only it's the new module that cannot be found.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that the `node_modules` volume in compose file is set as anonymous, anonymous volumes are preserved when containers are recreated, even with `--build`, the node still can't find the newly added module. See issues [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4337).

For now, I use these two commands to make it work since the [docker-compose v1.9](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-compose/) with [--renew-anon-volumes](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5596) witch I think should be used to handle this situation is not officially released yet:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up --build
```

Answer (score 42):

I came across the same issue and found that the solution was to remove the container and then fire it up again, i.e.

```
npm install some-package --save

docker-compose down

docker-compose up --build
```

> 17 Nov 20 - edited the above to make it more succinct

Comment: Specifically I needed to down before building.

Comment: ohh you saved my day

Comment: I can't upvote this enough!  I was stumped for a whole day on this.

Answer (score 3):

The volumes section is not present in the `docker run` that worked:

```
  volumes:
    - .:/home/app/sfsftp
    - /home/app/sfsftp/node_modules
```

I recommend try to mimic exactly the `docker run` that worked in the `docker-compose.yml` file. It is deleting the volumes section.

If deleting the volumes section works, well something you have or miss in your host is causing the problem when mounted.

Also I recommend upgrading your file to `version: '2'`. Docker compose behave strange with version 1 files.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @carlos-rafael-ramirez, but the volumes are an intended part of the setup which were previously working; see my added note at the end of my question for details.

Comment: The volumes are not the problem, but the content. If you dropped the volumes section and worked, now you know where the problem is. Something you are modifying injecting files from your host.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `docker-compose down` doesnt help, So i need to delete the volume manually.

Using `docker volume ls` to list all volumes
then `docker volume rm $VOLUME_ID` to remove the `anonymous` volumes

Additionally, you should name your `node_modules` volume, so it will be listed in `docker volume ls`

```
services: 
  sfsftp:
    ...
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/sfsftp
      - node_modules:/home/app/sfsftp/node_modules

volumes:
  node_modules:
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing **bash module not found** error when I was trying to containerize **alpine** based image with bash with command `bash -c "my commands"` and then I found out that **bash** is normally not installed in alpine based images so I had to switch to sh instead and command becomes `sh -c "my commands"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case above nothing helped, actually the issue was I think my local `node_modules` were being copied to docker image, after manually adding that missing package (nestjs) it still didn't worked, adding the `.dockerignore` worked.

```
node_modules
dist
```